# How to Apply Gradient to background view of iOS Swift App

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, cagradientlayer

I'm trying to apply a gradient as the background color of a View (main view of a storyboard). The code runs, but nothing changes. I'm using xCode Beta 2 and Swift.

Here's the code:

```
class Colors {
  let colorTop = UIColor(red: 192.0/255.0, green: 38.0/255.0, blue: 42.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
  let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 35.0/255.0, green: 2.0/255.0, blue: 2.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

  let gl: CAGradientLayer

  init() {
    gl = CAGradientLayer()
    gl.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gl.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
  }
}
```

then in the view controller:

```
  let colors = Colors()

  func refresh() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        var backgroundLayer = colors.gl
        backgroundLayer.frame = view.frame
        view.layer.insertSublayer(backgroundLayer, atIndex: 0)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I published a component that makes it easy, you can use it using cocoa pods, I suggest it because it is very simple and you can set it through interface builder on XCode. See more https://github.com/heuristisk/hkGraddiant

Comment: You are using UIColor elements on CAGradientLayer's property colors, but you must use CGColor instead!

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The Colors you're providing to gradient must be of type `CGColor`. So set your array of `CGColor` to `gl.colors`.

The correct code is :

```
class Colors {
    var gl:CAGradientLayer!

    init() {
        let colorTop = UIColor(red: 192.0 / 255.0, green: 38.0 / 255.0, blue: 42.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 35.0 / 255.0, green: 2.0 / 255.0, blue: 2.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

        self.gl = CAGradientLayer()
        self.gl.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        self.gl.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost works, but *ONLY* works for portrait. Right edge of screen is black.

Comment: this was key:  gl.frame = view.bounds;

Comment: I'm getting this error `fatal error: array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C`, when assigning to `.colors` property. What may be wrong with this?

Comment: I've fixed it. It's a bug in Swift, just store the array in variable with explicit type `[AnyObject]` and **then** assign it to `.colors` property.

Comment: let c: Array <AnyObject> = [colorTop, colorBottom]

Comment: for swift 1.0 the syntax would be `let c: [AnyObject] = [colorTop, colorBottom]`

Comment: Also, the frame of the layer should be updated. Please see the 'layoutSubviews' section at the @Leo Dabus 's answer.

Comment: Make sure you set gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds instead of gradientLayer.frame = view.frame.  

Also, if the gradientLayer is covering your button's image and label, then you want to use button.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, below: button.imageView.layer) instead of button.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayerr, at: 0 )

Answer (score 253):

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

---

You can design your own Gradient View as follow:

```
@IBDesignable
public class Gradient: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var startColor:   UIColor = .black { didSet { updateColors() }}
    @IBInspectable var endColor:     UIColor = .white { didSet { updateColors() }}
    @IBInspectable var startLocation: Double =   0.05 { didSet { updateLocations() }}
    @IBInspectable var endLocation:   Double =   0.95 { didSet { updateLocations() }}
    @IBInspectable var horizontalMode:  Bool =  false { didSet { updatePoints() }}
    @IBInspectable var diagonalMode:    Bool =  false { didSet { updatePoints() }}

    override public class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAGradientLayer.self }

    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { layer as! CAGradientLayer }

    func updatePoints() {
        if horizontalMode {
            gradientLayer.startPoint = diagonalMode ? .init(x: 1, y: 0) : .init(x: 0, y: 0.5)
            gradientLayer.endPoint   = diagonalMode ? .init(x: 0, y: 1) : .init(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        } else {
            gradientLayer.startPoint = diagonalMode ? .init(x: 0, y: 0) : .init(x: 0.5, y: 0)
            gradientLayer.endPoint   = diagonalMode ? .init(x: 1, y: 1) : .init(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        }
    }
    func updateLocations() {
        gradientLayer.locations = [startLocation as NSNumber, endLocation as NSNumber]
    }
    func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    }
    override public func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        updatePoints()
        updateLocations()
        updateColors()
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: don't forget import UIKit

Comment: Can you please explain this line:     override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622626-layerclass

Comment: what is the maximum number of location/positions/gradientstops could be applicable ? it seems more than certain number, iOS not rendering the gradient. The page is empty

Comment: This is a simple and nice way, good effort from you. Thank you, +1

Answer (score 123):

Just modifying the above mentioned answer.

[image]

```
func setGradientBackground() {
    let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 94.0/255.0, blue: 58.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
                
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
            
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
}
```

Then call this method within `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    setGradientBackground()
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

[image]

Comment: This puts a layer over existing elements so I cannot see anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: replace `self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)` with `self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)`, this will put the layer "below" all others

Comment: Is there a way to remove this gradient effect? Like a remove function?

Comment: Just remove the inserted sublayer

Comment: Is there a way to remove sublayers at certain layer. Like 0

Comment: @TylerRutt just give a name to your layer and then you can filter it regardless of its position

Comment: I add this to a subView like this `func setGradientBackground(_ aView: UIView)`, `aView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)`. But the gradient is not applied, any suggestions?

Comment: I move it into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` then it works:) Maybe `insertSublayer` will change the uiview's bounds.

Comment: Attention to the fact that CAGradientLayer property colors is a [Any]?, but the elements must be CGColor, not UIColor.  I made this mistake several times, and then nothing happens.

Answer (score 97):

And if you need to change the direction of the gradient you have to use startPoint and endPoint.

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

Comment: One of the problems you may face with this is that when you add a sublayer it may sit over all your other items, labels, image, etc. To overcome this create another view that sits below everything and set its constraints to that of the container you want the gradient in. Then set the gradient to be applied to this view. Subviews will then be inserted into this layer and not sit over anything else.

Answer (score 25):

I have these extensions:

```
@IBDesignable class GradientView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
    @IBInspectable var secondColor: UIColor = UIColor.green

    @IBInspectable var vertical: Bool = true

    lazy var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
        layer.startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        return layer
    }()

    //MARK: -

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        applyGradient()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        applyGradient()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        applyGradient()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateGradientFrame()
    }

    //MARK: -

    func applyGradient() {
        updateGradientDirection()
        layer.sublayers = [gradientLayer]
    }

    func updateGradientFrame() {
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }

    func updateGradientDirection() {
        gradientLayer.endPoint = vertical ? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1) : CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    }
}

@IBDesignable class ThreeColorsGradientView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
    @IBInspectable var secondColor: UIColor = UIColor.green
    @IBInspectable var thirdColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue

    @IBInspectable var vertical: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            updateGradientDirection()
        }
    }

    lazy var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor, thirdColor.cgColor]
        layer.startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        return layer
    }()

    //MARK: -

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        applyGradient()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        applyGradient()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        applyGradient()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateGradientFrame()
    }

    //MARK: -

    func applyGradient() {
        updateGradientDirection()
        layer.sublayers = [gradientLayer]
    }

    func updateGradientFrame() {
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }

    func updateGradientDirection() {
        gradientLayer.endPoint = vertical ? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1) : CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    }
}

@IBDesignable class RadialGradientView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var outsideColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
    @IBInspectable var insideColor: UIColor = UIColor.green

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        applyGradient()
    }

    func applyGradient() {
        let colors = [insideColor.cgColor, outsideColor.cgColor] as CFArray
        let endRadius = sqrt(pow(frame.width/2, 2) + pow(frame.height/2, 2))
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2, y: bounds.size.height / 2)
        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: colors, locations: nil)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context?.drawRadialGradient(gradient!, startCenter: center, startRadius: 0.0, endCenter: center, endRadius: endRadius, options: CGGradientDrawingOptions.drawsBeforeStartLocation)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        #if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
            applyGradient()
        #endif
    }
}
```

Usage:

[image]

### [image]

[image]

Comment: best not to add the layer in drawRect, just at setup time

Comment: adding this to my VC view block everything. All the elements are hidden under the gradient. Whats the way around

Comment: Changing the `self.layer.addSublayer(layer)` to `self.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)` seems to prevent the gradient from obfuscating everything in the interface builder (at least in my one test)

Answer (score 24):

In **Swift3** try this:

```
 func addGradient(){

    let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame.size = self.viewThatHoldsGradient.frame.size
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor,UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor] //Or any colors
    self.viewThatHoldsGradient.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

}
```

Comment: gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
for different gradient position.

Comment: colorWithAlphaComponent has been renamed to withAlphaComponent

Answer (score 21):

I made an UIView extension to apply a basic gradient to any view

```
extension UIView {
    func layerGradient() {
        let layer : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.frame.size = self.frame.size
        layer.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0)
        layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(frame.width / 20)

        let color0 = UIColor(red:250.0/255, green:250.0/255, blue:250.0/255, alpha:0.5).CGColor
        let color1 = UIColor(red:200.0/255, green:200.0/255, blue: 200.0/255, alpha:0.1).CGColor
        let color2 = UIColor(red:150.0/255, green:150.0/255, blue: 150.0/255, alpha:0.1).CGColor
        let color3 = UIColor(red:100.0/255, green:100.0/255, blue: 100.0/255, alpha:0.1).CGColor
        let color4 = UIColor(red:50.0/255, green:50.0/255, blue:50.0/255, alpha:0.1).CGColor
        let color5 = UIColor(red:0.0/255, green:0.0/255, blue:0.0/255, alpha:0.1).CGColor
        let color6 = UIColor(red:150.0/255, green:150.0/255, blue:150.0/255, alpha:0.1).CGColor

        layer.colors = [color0,color1,color2,color3,color4,color5,color6]
        self.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but it might be better to let the user pass the array of colors to that functions rather than hard coding them in it (unless you always want to apply the same gradient).

Comment: `CGPointMake(0.0,0.0)` can be replaced with `CGPointZero` for brevity

Comment: and you missed the main part - when to call it because it's frame may be invalid. Even forcing layout may not help if this view is not added to the hierarchy

Answer (score 18):

Try This , It's working for me,

```
  var gradientView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 35))
  let gradientLayer:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
  gradientLayer.frame.size = self.gradientView.frame.size
  gradientLayer.colors = 
  [UIColor.white.cgColor,UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(1).cgColor] 
  //Use diffrent colors
  gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

[image]

You can add starting and end point of gradient color.

```
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
```

[image]

For more detail description refer [Best Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41282225/4527240) or you can follow [CAGradientLayer From Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer)

Hopes This is help for some one.

Comment: Use following `startPoint` and `endPoint` for left to right gradient:
        `gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)`
and for top to bottom:
        `gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)`

Answer (score 17):

It's easy

```
    // MARK: - Gradient
extension CAGradientLayer {
    enum Point {
        case topLeft
        case centerLeft
        case bottomLeft
        case topCenter
        case center
        case bottomCenter
        case topRight
        case centerRight
        case bottomRight
        var point: CGPoint {
            switch self {
            case .topLeft:
                return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            case .centerLeft:
                return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
            case .bottomLeft:
                return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1.0)
            case .topCenter:
                return CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
            case .center:
                return CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            case .bottomCenter:
                return CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
            case .topRight:
                return CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
            case .centerRight:
                return CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
            case .bottomRight:
                return CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            }
        }
    }
    convenience init(start: Point, end: Point, colors: [CGColor], type: CAGradientLayerType) {
        self.init()
        self.startPoint = start.point
        self.endPoint = end.point
        self.colors = colors
        self.locations = (0..<colors.count).map(NSNumber.init)
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

**Use like this:-**

```
let fistColor = UIColor.white
let lastColor = UIColor.black
let gradient = CAGradientLayer(start: .topLeft, end: .topRight, colors: [fistColor.cgColor, lastColor.cgColor], type: .radial)
gradient.frame = yourView.bounds
yourView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Comment: Vote for enum Point

Comment: make (type: .axial)

Answer (score 11):

Extend `UIView` with this custom class.

---

**GradientView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class GradientView: UIView {

    // Default Colors
    var colors:[UIColor] = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.blueColor()]

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        // Must be set when the rect is drawn
        setGradient(colors[0], color2: colors[1])
    }

    func setGradient(color1: UIColor, color2: UIColor) {

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [color1.CGColor, color2.CGColor], [0, 1])!

        // Draw Path
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.width, frame.height))
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        path.addClip()
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(frame.width / 2, 0), CGPointMake(frame.width / 2, frame.height), CGGradientDrawingOptions())
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        // Ensure view has a transparent background color (not required)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

}
```

---

Usage

`gradientView.colors = [UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.8), UIColor.clearColor()]`

---

Result

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not calling `super.drawRect()`?

Comment: @Bearwithme no. Should work fine with `super.drawRect()` added.

Comment: Better to add to top of GradientView.swift: `@IBInspectable var topColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()`
`@IBInspectable var bottomColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()` Then you can see at settings
[Attribute Editor](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Em8Gn.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4

Add a view outlet

`@IBOutlet weak var gradientView: UIView!`

Add gradient to the view

```
func setGradient() {
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.frame = gradientView.layer.frame
    gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

Comment: If gradientView.layer.frame is not at (0,0), gradient layer is displaced. I would recommend using gradientView.layer.bounds .

Answer (score 6):

This code will work with **Swift 3.0**

```
class GradientView: UIView {

    override open class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        get{
            return CAGradientLayer.classForCoder()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let gradientLayer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
        let color1 = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.1).cgColor as CGColor
        let color2 = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.9).cgColor as CGColor
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.60, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.colors = [color2, color1]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Blahji Can you share example of usage..? And to use with a UILabel

Comment: Inserting a sublayer to a UILabel hides the text, so the best way to get what you want is to add the label and gradient layer to a UIView.

Answer (score 5):

I mixed the [Rohit Sisodia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5143043/rohit-sisodia) and [MGM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962845/mgm) answers

```
// MARK: - Gradient

public enum CAGradientPoint {
    case topLeft
    case centerLeft
    case bottomLeft
    case topCenter
    case center
    case bottomCenter
    case topRight
    case centerRight
    case bottomRight
    var point: CGPoint {
        switch self {
        case .topLeft:
            return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        case .centerLeft:
            return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        case .bottomLeft:
            return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1.0)
        case .topCenter:
            return CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
        case .center:
            return CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        case .bottomCenter:
            return CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        case .topRight:
            return CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        case .centerRight:
            return CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        case .bottomRight:
            return CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }
    }
}

extension CAGradientLayer {

    convenience init(start: CAGradientPoint, end: CAGradientPoint, colors: [CGColor], type: CAGradientLayerType) {
        self.init()
        self.frame.origin = CGPoint.zero
        self.startPoint = start.point
        self.endPoint = end.point
        self.colors = colors
        self.locations = (0..<colors.count).map(NSNumber.init)
        self.type = type
    }
}

extension UIView {

    func layerGradient(startPoint:CAGradientPoint, endPoint:CAGradientPoint ,colorArray:[CGColor], type:CAGradientLayerType ) {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer(start: .topLeft, end: .topRight, colors: colorArray, type: type)
        gradient.frame.size = self.frame.size
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

To Use write:-

```
        btnUrdu.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        btnUrdu.layer.masksToBounds = true 
        btnUrdu.layerGradient(startPoint: .centerRight, endPoint: .centerLeft, colorArray: [UIColor.appBlue.cgColor, UIColor.appLightBlue.cgColor], type: .axial)
```

Output:

[image: OutPut]

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add a gradient to a view, and then anchor it using auto-layout.

```
    class GradientView: UIView {

    private let gradient: CAGradientLayer = {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        let topColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.98, green:0.96, blue:0.93, alpha:0.5)
        let bottomColor: UIColor = UIColor.white
        layer.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
        layer.locations = [0,1]
        return layer
    }()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        gradient.frame = frame
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradient.frame = bounds

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use HEX instead of RGBA, just drag a new empty .swift and add below mentioned code:

```
     import UIKit

    extension UIColor {
        convenience init(rgba: String) {
            var red:   CGFloat = 0.0
            var green: CGFloat = 0.0
            var blue:  CGFloat = 0.0
            var alpha: CGFloat = 1.0

            if rgba.hasPrefix("#") {
                let index   = advance(rgba.startIndex, 1)
                let hex     = rgba.substringFromIndex(index)
                let scanner = NSScanner(string: hex)
                var hexValue: CUnsignedLongLong = 0
                if scanner.scanHexLongLong(&hexValue) {
                    switch (count(hex)) {
                    case 3:
                        red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xF00) >> 8)       / 15.0
                        green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0F0) >> 4)       / 15.0
                        blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x00F)              / 15.0
                    case 4:
                        red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xF000) >> 12)     / 15.0
                        green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0F00) >> 8)      / 15.0
                        blue  = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00F0) >> 4)      / 15.0
                        alpha = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000F)             / 15.0
                    case 6:
                        red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)   / 255.0
                        green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8)    / 255.0
                        blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x0000FF)           / 255.0
                    case 8:
                        red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
                        green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
                        blue  = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)  / 255.0
                        alpha = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000000FF)         / 255.0
                    default:
                        print("Invalid RGB string, number of characters after '#' should be either 3, 4, 6 or 8")
                    }
                } else {
                    println("Scan hex error")
                }
            } else {
                print("Invalid RGB string, missing '#' as prefix")
            }
            self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
        }
}
```

similarly, drag another empty .swift file and add below mentioned code:

```
    class Colors {
    let colorTop = UIColor(rgba: "##8968CD").CGColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(rgba: "#5D478B").CGColor

    let gl: CAGradientLayer

    init() {
        gl = CAGradientLayer()
        gl.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
        gl.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
    }
}
```

after that in view controller, under class instantiate your 'Color' class like this:

```
let colors = Colors()
```

add a new function:

```
func refresh() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        var backgroundLayer = colors.gl
        backgroundLayer.frame = view.frame
        view.layer.insertSublayer(backgroundLayer, atIndex: 0)
    }
```

state that function in viewDidLoad:

```
refresh()
```

you're done :))
using HEX is way too easy if compared to RGBA. :D

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 - Uses only textures and SKSpriteNode, doesn't require UIView

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class GradientSpriteNode : SKSpriteNode
{
    convenience init(size: CGSize, colors: [UIColor], locations: [CGFloat])
    {
        let texture = GradientSpriteNode.texture(size: size, colors: colors, locations: locations)
        self.init(texture: texture, color:SKColor.clear, size: texture.size())
    }

    private override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: SKColor, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private static func texture(size: CGSize, colors: [UIColor], locations: [CGFloat]) -> SKTexture
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colors.map{$0.cgColor} as CFArray, locations: locations)!
        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: 0), end: CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height), options: CGGradientDrawingOptions())
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return SKTexture(image: image!)

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let gradient = GradientSpriteNode(
        size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100),
        colors: [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue],
        locations: [0.0, 1.0])
addChild(gradient)
```

Comment: what is the performance of spritekitnode versus cagradientlayer?  having to render the image seems like it would be slower.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but usually the ca** classes are much much more performant than the sprite kit ones.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code :

```
extension UIView {
func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor]) -> Void {
 let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
 gradient.frame = self.bounds
 gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
 gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x : 0.0, y : 0.5)
 gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x :1.0, y: 0.5)
 self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
 }
}
```

call this function like :

```
  self.mainView.applyGradient(colours: [.green, .blue])
```

Answer (score 3):

**Xcode 11 | Swift 5**

If anybody is looking for a quick and easy way to add a gradient to a view:

```
extension UIView {
    
    func addGradient(colors: [UIColor] = [.blue, .white], locations: [NSNumber] = [0, 2], startPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0), endPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0), type: CAGradientLayerType = .axial){
        
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        
        gradient.frame.size = self.frame.size
        gradient.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

        // Iterates through the colors array and casts the individual elements to cgColor
        // Alternatively, one could use a CGColor Array in the first place or do this cast in a for-loop
        gradient.colors = colors.map{ $0.cgColor }
        
        gradient.locations = locations
        gradient.startPoint = startPoint
        gradient.endPoint = endPoint
        
        // Insert the new layer at the bottom-most position
        // This way we won't cover any other elements
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Examples on how to use the extension:

```
// Testing
view.addGradient()
        
// Two Colors
view.addGradient(colors: [.init(rgb: 0x75BBDB), .black], locations: [0, 3])
        
// Full Blown
view.addGradient(colors: [.init(rgb: 0x75BBDB), .black], locations: [0, 3], startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.5), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 2.0), type: .axial)
```

Optionally, use the following to input hex numbers `.init(rgb: 0x75BBDB)`

```
extension UIColor {
   convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
       self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
   }

   convenience init(rgb: Int) {
       self.init(
           red: (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF,
           green: (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF,
           blue: rgb & 0xFF
       )
   }
}
```

Comment: Anyone with any corner radius going on would benefit from:
`gradient.cornerRadius = self.layer.cornerRadius` - Just be careful not to apply the corner radius after the gradient.

Answer (score 2):

To add gradient into layer, add:

```
let layer = CAGradientLayer()
layer.frame = CGRect(x: 64, y: 64, width: 120, height: 120)
layer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

Comment: Please do add some explanation with it too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a swift extension where you can pass any amount of arbitrary colors. It will remove any previous gradients before inserting one and it will return the newly inserted gradient layer for further manipulation if needed:

```
    extension UIView {

    /**
     Given an Array of CGColor, it will:
        - Remove all sublayers of type CAGradientLayer.
        - Create and insert a new CAGradientLayer.

     - Parameters: 
        - colors: An Array of CGColor with the colors for the gradient fill

     - Returns: The newly created gradient CAGradientLayer
     */
    func layerGradient(colors c:[CGColor])->CAGradientLayer {
        self.layer.sublayers = self.layer.sublayers?.filter(){!($0 is CAGradientLayer)}
        let layer : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.frame.size = self.frame.size
        layer.frame.origin = CGPointZero
        layer.colors = c
        self.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)
        return layer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Specify the Frame of the View, where you want to show the gradient color.

```
let firstColor =  UIColor(red: 69/255, green: 90/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

 let secondColor = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 44/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [ firstColor, secondColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 64)// You can mention frame here

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation for setting this up in a reusable Util class file

In your Xcode project:

1. Create a new Swift class call it UI_Util.swift, and populate it as follows:

   ```
   import Foundation
   import UIKit

   class UI_Util {

       static func setGradientGreenBlue(uiView: UIView) {

           let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 15.0/255.0, green: 118.0/255.0, blue: 128.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
           let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 84.0/255.0, green: 187.0/255.0, blue: 187.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

           let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
           gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
           gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
           gradientLayer.frame = uiView.bounds

           uiView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
       }
   }
   ```

---

2. Now you can call the function from any ViewController like so:

   ```
   class AbcViewController: UIViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()                
           UI_Util.setGradientGreen(uiView: self.view)
       }
   ```

*Thanks to katwal-Dipak's answer for the function code*

Answer (score 1):

**For swift to apply CAGradientLayer to any object (Horizontal and vertical)**

```
func makeGradientColor(`for` object : AnyObject , startPoint : CGPoint , endPoint : CGPoint) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    gradient.colors = [(UIColor(red: 59.0/255.0, green: 187.0/255.0, blue: 182.0/255.0, alpha: 1.00).cgColor), (UIColor(red: 57.0/255.0, green: 174.0/255.0, blue: 236.0/255.0, alpha: 1.00).cgColor)]
    gradient.locations = [0.0 , 1.0]

    gradient.startPoint = startPoint
    gradient.endPoint = endPoint
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: object.frame.size.width, height: object.frame.size.height)
    return gradient
}
```

**How to use**

```
let start : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
let end : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = self.makeGradientColor(for: vwTop, startPoint: start, endPoint: end)
vwTop.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

let start1 : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
let end1 : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
let gradient1: CAGradientLayer = self.makeGradientColor(for: vwTop, startPoint: start1, endPoint: end1)
vwBottom.layer.insertSublayer(gradient1, at: 0)
```

[You can check output here](https://prnt.sc/jnztr7)

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called Chameleon (https://github.com/viccalexander/Chameleon) which one can use for gradient colors. It even has styles of gradient to implement.  This is how you can add it in swift 4 podfile
 pod 'ChameleonFramework/Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/ViccAlexander/Chameleon.git', :branch => 'wip/swift4'

```
import ChameleonFramework

let colors:[UIColor] = [
  UIColor.flatPurpleColorDark(), 
  UIColor.flatWhiteColor()
]
view.backgroundColor = GradientColor(.TopToBottom, frame: view.frame, colors: colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner code that lets you pass any `UIColor` to an instance of the `GradientLayer` class:

```
class GradientLayer {

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer
    let colorTop: CGColor
    let colorBottom: CGColor

    init(colorTop: UIColor, colorBottom: UIColor) {
        self.colorTop = colorTop.CGColor
        self.colorBottom = colorBottom.CGColor
        gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have view Collection (Multiple View) do this

```
  func setGradientBackground() {
    let v:UIView
    for v in viewgradian
    //here viewgradian is your view Collection Outlet name
    {
        let layer:CALayer
        var arr = [AnyObject]()
        for layer in v.layer.sublayers!
        {
           arr.append(layer)
        }

        let colorTop = UIColor(red: 216.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [ colorBottom, colorTop]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.frame = v.bounds
        v.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to use extension on swift 3

```
extension CALayer {
    func addGradienBorder(colors:[UIColor] = [UIColor.red,UIColor.blue], width:CGFloat = 1) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame =  CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1.0, y:0.5)
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map({$0.cgColor})

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = width
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer

        self.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

use to your view, example

```
yourView.addGradienBorder(color: UIColor.black, opacity: 0.1, offset: CGSize(width:2 , height: 5), radius: 3, viewCornerRadius: 3.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting an Objective C version of the answer. Tested and works on iOS13

```
// Done here so that constraints have completed and the frame is correct.
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews { 
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    UIColor *colorTop = [UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)192.0/255.0 green: 38.0/255.0 blue: 42.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *colorBottom = [UIColor colorWithRed: 35.0/255.0 green: 2.0/255.0 blue: 2.0/255.0 alpha: 1.0];
    CAGradientLayer *gl = [CAGradientLayer new];
    [gl setColors:@[(id)[colorTop CGColor], (id)[colorBottom CGColor]]];
    [gl setLocations:@[@0.0f, @1.0f]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    CALayer *backgroundLayer = gl;
    backgroundLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:backgroundLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is you can't add a gradient to a UILabel without clearing the text. One simple workaround is to use a UIButton and disable user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI: You can use the `LinearGradient` struct as the first element in a `ZStack`. As the "bottom" of the `ZStack`, it will serve as the background color. `AngularGradient` and `RadialGradient` are also available.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            // Put other content here; it will appear on top of the background gradient
        }
    }
}
```