# Shade and mix two color with percent , horizontally and vertically in swift

Tags: swift, background-color, uicolor, cagradientlayer

I wanted to Mix two colors shaded and divided equally.

[image]

(Ignore the buttons inside of it)
Also, I want to apply this functionality somewhere horizontally and somewhere vertically.

Thank you.

Comment: You could use a `CAGradientLayer`, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380535/how-to-apply-gradient-to-background-view-of-ios-swift-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are looking for is `CAGradientLayer`.

For Vertical

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = self.gradientView.bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor] //Add different color here
self.gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer) //Add Layer in your View
```

For Horizontal simply set `startPoint` and `endPoint` with `gradientLayer`.

```
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
```