# Adding gradient on background image of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cagradientlayer

I have a `UITableView` inside of a `UIViewController`. I'm attempting to apply a gradient over a background image in a `UITableViewCell`. I can get a gradient to draw, but it's drawing a clean line between the colors instead of a gradient.

In my `cellForRowAt`, I assign an object to my `CustomTableViewCell`, like so:

```
  let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
  // all the standard data source, delegate stuff for uitableviews

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    let scheduleItem = scheduleData[indexPath.row]
    cell.scheduleStruct = scheduleItem
    return cell
  }
```

Over in `CustomTableViewCell`, I've got this property declared:

```
    public var scheduleStruct: FullScheduleStruct? {
    didSet {
      configureCell()
    }
    // emptyView to throw on top of a background image
    var gradientView: UIView?
```

I'm also using `Kingfisher` to pull images off of the internet, which is what's going on with the `ImageResource(downloadURL: url)` part. The `configureCell()` method called when `scheduleStruct` is set like this:

```
    private func configureCell() {

    // get the background image
    if let url = scheduleStruct?.show.image?.original {
      let imageUrl = ImageResource(downloadURL: url)
      backgroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
      backgroundImageView.kf.setImage(with: imageUrl)

      // configure the gradientView
      gradientView = UIView(frame: backgroundImageView.frame)
      let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
      gradient.frame = gradientView!.frame
      gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
      // gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
      gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
      gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
      gradientView!.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
      backgroundImageView.insertSubview(gradientView!, at: 0)
    }
```

Any suggestions re: where my mistake lies are greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: What do you mean by drawing a clean line between the colors"? Could you include an image that shows this result (and possibly also the result you're expecting)?

Comment: try using this custom gradient view https://stackoverflow.com/a/37243106/2303865

Comment: Your gradient code is working fine in a playground.  I suspect the issue is with your url or your backgroundImageView.kf.setImage -- if you comment that out do you get your gradient?

Comment: @DavidShaw Thank you! It turns out I had a timing issue that your suggestion enabled me to see. I found a slightly different method signature for setting the image that had a completion handler in it. Using that as an alternative solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [David Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2969719/david-shaw)'s suggestion, I commented out this line in `configureCell()`

```
  // backgroundImageView.kf.setImage(with: imageUrl)
```

and the gradient drew properly. I deduced I had a timing issue because I'm getting the image asynchronously.

I looked through the method signatures and saw there's one with a completion handler, so I used it instead and it worked:

```
  backgroundImageView.kf.setImage(with: imageUrl, completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageUrl) in
    // do stuff
  })
```

...so I did [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N0OHdRFcJA).