# add gradient to UILabel in a collectionView cell - swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add gradient to an UILabel in a collectionViewCell. To add gradient I'm using this function:

```
extension UIView
{
     func gradient(colors: [Any], startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint, opacity: Float, location: [NSNumber]?) {
         let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
         gradientLayer.frame = bounds
         gradientLayer.colors = colors
         gradientLayer.startPoint = startPoint
         gradientLayer.endPoint = endPoint
         gradientLayer.opacity = opacity
         gradientLayer.locations = location
         layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
     }
}
```

and in my collectionViewCell :

```
@IBOutlet weak var discount: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    discount.gradient(colors: [green,blue], startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5), opacity: 1, location: [0.5,0.5])
}
```

But it's not showing anything. Adding shadow works fine but adding gradient not showing anything. Why is that happen?

Comment: @meaning-matters I've updated post

Comment: Why not to subclass UILabel and put that code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. ?

Comment: The first thing that strikes me is that although you create the gradient layer with a frame as the bounds of the view it will not stay the same.  So if/when the view is resized the gradient layer will not be sized accordingly.  I can't remember what size the view will start but that could be the issue.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I wanna say yes it's about bounds, but when I use adding shadow (same procedure) it works fine

Comment: @HosAp reference to subclass UIView and create a gradient view so you don't add multiple gradient layers on top of each other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380535/how-to-apply-gradient-to-background-view-of-ios-swift-app/37243106?s=1|57.9597#37243106

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your extension to

```
extension UIView
{
    func gradient(colors: [CGColor], startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint, opacity: Float, location: [NSNumber]?) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        gradientLayer.startPoint = startPoint
        gradientLayer.endPoint = endPoint
        gradientLayer.opacity = opacity
        gradientLayer.locations = location
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

Call it from collectionView class as

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        discount.gradient(colors: [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor], startPoint: CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.0), endPoint: CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 1.0), opacity: 1.0, location: [0,1])
}
```

Tested and working.

[image]

Comment: still not working. It's weird adding shadow works but adding gradient not working

Comment: have you changed the extension function you had used [Any] in colors it should be CGColor

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that! I was sending UIColor instead of CGColor. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem with this code is that every time `layoutSubviews()` is called, it will add another gradient sublayer. If you rotate the device, for example, `layoutSubviews()` will be called again for each rotation. That's probably not what you want. Probably the cleanest way to fix that problem is to switch from a UIView extension to a custom subclass of UIView that has a gradientLayer property that gets created at init time, and layoutSubviews simply changes the layer's frame.

Comment: I completely missed the CGColor issue as I just did it automatically.  I agree that this is going to add a new gradient layer each time `layoutSubviews` is called and that is definitely not what you want to be doing.  I also agree that subclassing is probably the way to go here which is what we did in v2 (ObjectiveC) and v3 (Swift) of our app.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I add a sublayer to a view I like to make sure the frame is always updated in `layoutSubviews`:

```
public override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
}
```

You'll need to keep a reference to the gradient layer as a property in your view.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is making gradient text then you must to the following:

1. Embed your label in a UIView and connect outlet (say `discountContainer`)
2. Add a gradient layer to **that view** (instead of label).
   `discountContainer.gradient(colors: [green,blue], startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5), opacity: 1, location: [0.5,0.5])`
3. Set the label as the views mask
   `discountContainer.mask = discount`

Result:

[image]

---

EDITED:

If you need to make gradient only on the background then you should keep the reference to `CAGradientLayer`.

```
extension UIView
{
     func gradient(colors: [Any], startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint, opacity: Float, location: [NSNumber]?) -> CAGradientLayer {
         let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
         gradientLayer.frame = bounds
         gradientLayer.colors = colors
         gradientLayer.startPoint = startPoint
         gradientLayer.endPoint = endPoint
         gradientLayer.opacity = opacity
         gradientLayer.locations = location
         layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
         return layer
     }
}
```

and in your collectionViewCell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var discount: UILabel!
var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    gradientLayer = discount.gradient(colors: [green,blue], startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5), opacity: 1, location: [0.5,0.5])
}

public override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer?.frame = bounds
}
```

Comment: I think you have to mix both of my answers :) Embed label in a view, add gradient to that view, and update gradients frame to be equal to that view's bounds in layoutSubviews method

Answer (score 0):

If you have used cocoapods, the Chameleon Framework offers a very easy solution to creating gradient colors. To use it, install cocoapods, then install Chameleon Framework. Put

```
import ChameleonFramework
```

at the top of the UIViewController.

The link for the usage after the installation is below.

https://github.com/ViccAlexander/Chameleon#gradient-colors-1

It looks like it as is easy as the line of code below if you are using Swift.

```
UIColor(gradientStyle:UIGradientStyle, withFrame:CGRect, andColors:[UIColor])
```

Just set the background of your UILabel using that line of code above.