# Navigation Bar Background Image Does not Extend To Search Bar

Tags: ios, swift

so I previously had my search controller embedded inside the Navigation bar so that the gradient of the navigation bar also covered the search bar.

Suddenly, I believe from an XCode update, I found that now the navigation bar's background color stops firmly at the top of the search controller.I am having trouble pin-pointing why this happens.

This is my current code, which previously worked. Any thoughts?

```
private func setNavigationBarAesthetics() {

    if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {

        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "testbg"), for: .default)


    }

    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.definesPresentationContext = false
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true

    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
}
```

[image]

Comment: "it suddenly changed" What does that mean?

Comment: XCode update I suspect.

Comment: OK but you are not explaining what the problem is. Saying "changed" or "pinpoint the issue" does not tell us what the issue _is_.

Comment: Oh, I need the blue gradient to encompass, the entire search bar.  I'll clarify that, apologies

Comment: OK so where does the gradient come from? Give us enough code to allow us to _reproduce the problem_ ourselves.

Comment: Updated the original question

Comment: OK so you're doing this wrong. Make the gradient the background image of the nav bar. (In iOS 13 you would use the UIBarAppearance to do that. But even in iOS 12 what you're doing is a totally wrong hack; they hand you this functionality, you should use what they've given you.)

Comment: Unable to find any further links on how to do this. This link shows how to insert a `CAGradientLayer` into the `view.sublayer` , which is giving me the same result as what I already have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380535/how-to-apply-gradient-to-background-view-of-ios-swift-app

Comment: @matt using this link to implement your suggestion, the gradient still stops above the search controller https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/06/21/resize-navbar-gradient-ios/

Comment: But hacking with the search bar. Just set the navigation bar appearance's background image to the gradient image and stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with that code. First, stop hacking the search bar:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear // no
self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage() // no
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // no
searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent // no
```

Second, stop hacking the navigation bar: Delete the GradientView entirely from your code.

```
class GradientView: UIView { // no
```

Just use the tools that the framework gives you. Set the navigation bar's background image (to an image of a gradient) and *stop*. The search controller's search bar will *automatically* integrate itself correctly into the navigation bar:

[image]

**EDIT** Okay, so it turns out that this is issue is iOS 13 only. That's because what you're doing is not how to add a background image to a navigation bar in iOS 13. You will have to bifurcate your code:

```
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let app = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        app.backgroundImage = im // the gradient image
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = app
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = app
    } else {
        // your old code goes here
    }
```

Comment: I followed your post and it simplified my coding. But it doesn't change the outcome. What does your code look like for that picture?

Comment: Hi @markocalvocruz I told you what I do. I set the navigation bar's background image to an image of a gradient, and I set the navigation item's `searchController` to my UISearchController. That's all (except for making the rounded-rect background white). No trickery.

Comment: The VC is 100% embedded inside a Navigation Controller in the Storyboard. I just updated my question to reflect all of the code changes according to your answer

Comment: Still full of wrong hacks. Delete `navigationBar.isTranslucent = true`. Delete `navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear`. Delete all the stuff about the image bounds. Just do what I said and _no more_.

Comment: Also take out the `if let textField = ...` stuff. Just do _only what I said_. Prove to yourself that it works. Then you can start playing around if you just can't live without hacking.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect your suggestions. Unsure how I'd change the gradient function without bounds

Comment: Well, use _any_ image as a test, just to prove to yourself that this normally just works. Don't worry about the size of the image. A solid color 100x100 image will do.

Comment: Yup! This is the issue -  the navigation bar's background image does not extend to the search bar, see my updated question

Comment: Is this iOS 13?

Comment: target deployment iOS 11.0, but I believe the problem started with an XCode update. It used to work even with my old hacky code

Comment: I didn't ask what the target deployment was. I asked what _this_ is. What system are we actually running on when you see the problem?

Comment: Ah! Yes the simulator is running iOS 13.0!

Comment: Okay. So, what you're doing is not how to set the background image in iOS 13. You'll need to use `available` blocks to bifurcate your code. I'll post iOS 13 code for setting the background image.

Comment: awesome! The new code fixed it. Thank you so much, I appreciate your patience

Comment: No problem! Sorry it took so long to narrow it down.

Comment: Do we know the code for fixing the gradient on iOS 11 & 12? This fixed iOS13 but broke it on older versions

Comment: You said “This is my current code, which previously worked”. So you keep using it on iOS 11 and 12, as I said in my answer.

Comment: My previous code was a gradient view that everybody told me to delete, which I did.  I now set the gradient with `navigationBar.setBackgroundImage` but the gradient does not extend to the searchbar, like the picture in the question

Comment: Well fine. But _this_ question was about iOS 13. I answered that. The end. If you now have a different question, ask a new question.

Comment: @matt How did you manage below ios13? I set images navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(img, for: .default) but it doesn't work at all

Comment: @zramled It's the OP who was "managing below iOS 13", and the OP's question does not show that code. My answer is about iOS 13 and later, because that is what the question was.

Comment: @matt I figure it out and I just updated my answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5 that handle ios 12 and 13.**

This is based from the answer with matt.

```
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let app = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        app.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "img")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = app
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = app
    } else {
       // iOS 12 to below
       if let navigationbar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
       navigationbar.barTintColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "img")!)
       navigationbar.isTranslucent = false
    }
   }
```