# Swift Darkmode Background Gradient

Tags: swift, background, gradient, ios-darkmode

I found this bit of code online to add a gradient to my project and it does add the gradient beautifully

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.systemBackground.cgColor, UIColor.systemGray2.cgColor]
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

However, the colors don't change when I change between dark and light mode. I'm not sure why this is happening since I am using dark mode compatible colors. If anyone knows how to fix that bug please let me know.

Comment: cgColors are not dynamic

Comment: You can use this custom gradient view https://stackoverflow.com/a/37243106/2303865

Answer (score 1):

When you use adaptive colors with CALayers, colors are not updating when switching appearance live in the app. You can solve this by making use of the `traitCollectionDidChange(_:)` method.

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *),
        let hasUserInterfaceStyleChanged = previousTraitCollection?.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: traitCollection),
        hasUserInterfaceStyleChanged {
        // update layer
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that out but it doesn't seem to update every single time.  At the moment I am doing the gradient layout in viewWillLayoutSubviews, then I added the code you provided right after. Any Ideas?