# Swift: How to mask a UICollectionView's background to only be seen behind visible cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, gradient, calayer

### Introduction

Hello,

I have added a background view with a `CAGradientLayer`, and my `UICollectionViewCells` have a hole in them to see the background. So far, it all looks great:

[image]

---

### The Problem

However, when I scroll to the very top (and also the very bottom) of the `UICollectionView`, you can see the gradient background past the top of the first cell:

[image]

---

### Question

What is something I can do to "mask" or "constrain" the gradient background to only being visible behind the cells, and not outside of the cell's frame/bounds?

---

### Edit

This solves the top part, but I'm still not sure about the overflow on the bottom:

```swift
        let header = UIView()
        header.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        collectionView.addSubview(header)
        
        header.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(self.view)
            make.left.right.equalTo(self.view)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.collectionView.snp.top)
        }
```

Comment: Not related to your question but you can use that same shapelayer approach in your gradient view https://stackoverflow.com/a/37243106/2303865