# Two separate background colors for top and bottom view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, viewcontroller

**Problem:**

I would like to set two different background colors for a view controller programmatically.

**Code:**

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
```

or

```
func setGradientBackground() {
        
        let colorTop = UIColor.black.cgColor
        let colorBottom = backgroundGray.cgColor
                    
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: -1)
        //gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
                
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
    }
```

Do I need to use a gradient system to obtain this? The gradient system is well gradient and I would like more of a solid top and bottom color.

How can I obtain the desired output of the image below
[image]

Comment: A gradient gives a smooth transition between colors. You want two extra subviews each with the desired background color.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380535/how-to-apply-gradient-to-background-view-of-ios-swift-app might give you a better idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on this answer [How to Apply Gradient to background view of iOS Swift App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380535/how-to-apply-gradient-to-background-view-of-ios-swift-app)

I modified the `CAGradientLayer#locations` and `CAGradientLayer#colors` to provide a "hard" stop between the colors

[image]

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var greeting = "Hello, playground"

class Gradient: UIView {
    var startColor:   UIColor = .white { didSet { updateColors() }}
    var endColor:     UIColor = .red { didSet { updateColors() }}
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAGradientLayer.self }
    
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { layer as! CAGradientLayer }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        updatePoints()
        updateLocations()
        updateColors()
    }
    
    func updatePoints() {
        gradientLayer.startPoint = diagonalMode ? .init(x: 1, y: 0) : .init(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint   = diagonalMode ? .init(x: 0, y: 1) : .init(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    }

    func updateLocations() {
        gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]
    }

    func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    }
}

let view = Gradient(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
```

I might also consider devising a composite/compund view, one which had two views to manage the background color and a third which was laid over the top of them, which acted as the "content" view.  It would require a little bit more juggling though.

Comment: Clever use of a gradient. But seems so inefficient compared to just adding two view with the desired background colors.

Comment: "because the stops are based on percentile position, it's possible that a large enough height might cause line between the two colors to fade". You can use booth stop points at 0.5.

Comment: @HangarRash I have an improved version of my code above where I can set the direction angle

Comment: @HangarRash I don't disagree, in fact I even suggested making a compound/composite view instead. Expect (in my mind) it becomes a little more complicated as you need to constantly manage those views so they are always in the background - half a dozen of this, half a dozen of that

Comment: @LeoDabus Hmm, that curious, I'm sure it use to complain about the two stops been equal, will update

Comment: @MadProgrammer - you can omit `traitCollectionDidChange(...)` -- it doesn't change any of the properties, so it's not needed. You may also want to implement `init` so the view will display properly with its defaults: https://pastebin.com/4JZD3MTd

Comment: @DonMag I just took the example from the previous question. I could also omit `horizontalMode` and `diagonalMode` which would better handled as an `enum` and I think the original example made use `IBDesignable` and related elements, so I think the intention was to make it usable in story boards